# PHP 2 step process to 1

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently using a wp gift certificate plugin that works in the following way.

Step 1: Enter amount of gift certificate and click continue
Step 2: Enter recipient details, etc. and purchase

I want to remove step 1 so step 2 loads instead. Each time I try it errors with either headers already being sent or errors I just can't figure out.

There is only 1 gift certificate setup and no more will be added later, that is `[wpgft id=0]`.

There are 2 files that I need to modify for this process and have tried but to no avail.

- http://pastebin.com/thtQ25FB

Line 347 `//Setup the function to show the buttons based on Short Codes.`
to
Line 390 `add_shortcode('wpgft', 'showButton');`

- http://pastebin.com/hR9XU4ux

Line 59 `//Check to see if the form was submitted.`
to
Line 269 `add_filter('the_posts', 'wpgft_clearSlate');`

In short, I want to remove the first step process of inputting a monetary value and having a submit button, and rather just have the form with the monetary value input on 1 page. I don't mind hard-coding the wpgft id as 0 as there will only ever be 1 gift certificate with a preset value of 0.

Comment: Can you post the error information?

Comment: A bit too much code to wade through. As Chris said, the errors you get will help tremendously.

Comment: @Chris: I'm literally playing around with code to try and get everything on to 1 step so the errors that come up are all over the place. Can you see anything that makes it easy to turn this into a one step process?

Comment: @Robbie: Sorry, just trying to figure out the easiest way to implement everything on one page.

Comment: @Dave It's a lot to go through, but my best suggestion is to do a search on the second file for `$_POST` and everywhere you find that, you need to connect it with a value from the actual code. My expectation is that the errors you have are because you're setting values to `null` because it's still looking to `$_POST`

Comment: @Chris: Thanks, I'll give it a shot and post an update shortly. Trouble is knowing where to start to be honest, but thank you. Stay tuned.